# Создание собственного поля в админке django

Tags: python, виджет, django, django-admin

Добрый день. У меня есть задача хранить в базе данных строку, длиной 24*7, состоящую из нулей и единиц.
В админке я хочу видеть семь колонок по 24 checkbox'а в каждой: если галочка установлена, то на соответствующем месте в строке в БД ставится 1, если снята — 0.

Для реализации этого я пытаюсь написать собственный field и widget

Далее привожу описание модели (частично) model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from places.widgets import *
from places.fields import *

class Place(models.Model):
    …
    time =          HoursWorkByWeekField()
    …
```

Далее, собственно, fields.py

```
from django.forms import fields
from django.db import models

from places.widgets import HoursWorkByWeekWidget

class HoursWorkByWeekField(models.CharField):
    widget = HoursWorkByWeekWidget

    def __init__(self):
        super(HoursWorkByWeekField, self).__init__(max_length=24*7, min_length=24*7)

    def to_python(self, value):
        return list(value)

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        result = []
        for i in range(24*7):
            if value[i] :
                result += ['1']
            else :
                result += ['0']
        return ''.join(result)
```

и widgets.py

```
from django.forms import widgets

class HoursWorkByDayWidget(widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    def render(self, name, attrs=None):
        choices = range(0,24,1)
        return widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple.render(self, name, attrs, choices)

class HoursWorkByWeekWidget(widgets.MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        widgets = (
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
            HoursWorkByDayWidget(),
        )
        super(HoursWorkByWeekWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)
```

При попытке выполнить syncdb после в БД для атрибута time не создается.

Comment: а что пишет в выводе?

Comment: В выводе ничего не пишет: проходит без ошибок, но поле не создается

Comment: @actionless Упс. Заметил, что у меня 
class HoursWorkByWeekField(fields.CharField):
заменил на 
class HoursWorkByWeekField(models.CharField):

Теперь при попытке выполнить syncdb выдает 

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: а трейс какой-то был с ошибкой?

Comment: @actionless нет: писал «TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases unhashable type: 'dict'»

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить

```
__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
```

[The SubfieldBase metaclass](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-model-fields/#the-subfieldbase-metaclass)